# Can i put a list of objects in an array or something similar? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am very new to coding and i wanted to know if i could put a list of objects in an array for collision.

instead of writing... if player.hitTestObject(wall1) then wall 2 then wall 3?

can i put them all in one array or something else so i can just say if player.hitTestObject(everywall)

Thanks. my code looks like this and i have around 30 walls.

I would be very grateful if someone posted an example.

```
function keydown(event:KeyboardEvent) :void {

switch(event.keyCode){

    case Keyboard.LEFT :

    hero.x -= 10;

    if(hero.hitTestObject(w1) || hero.hitTestObject(w2) || hero.hitTestObject(w3) || hero.hitTestObject(w4)){
    hero.x +=10;}
    break;

    case Keyboard.RIGHT:
    hero.x +=10;
    if(hero.hitTestObject(w1) || hero.hitTestObject(w2) || hero.hitTestObject(w3) || hero.hitTestObject(w4)){
    hero.x -=10;}
    break;

    case Keyboard.UP:
    hero.y -=10;
    if(hero.hitTestObject(w1) || hero.hitTestObject(w2) ||  hero.hitTestObject(w3) || hero.hitTestObject(w4)){
    hero.y +=10;}

    break;

    case Keyboard.DOWN:
    hero.y += 10;
    if(hero.hitTestObject(w1) || hero.hitTestObject(w2) ||  hero.hitTestObject(w3) || hero.hitTestObject(w4)){
    hero.y -=10;}
    break;

    default  :
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in the [Actionscript Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29), `hitTestObject()` takes a `DisplayObject` as a parameter, not any kind of list.

If you want, you can implement this kind of functionality yourself.

```
function myHitTest(obj:DisplayObject, arr:Array):Boolean {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    //for (var item:DisplayObject in arr) {
        var item:DisplayObject = arr[i]
        if (obj.hitTestObject(item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And then you can use that...

```
if(myHitTest(hero,[w1,w2,w3]))
    ...
```

or

```
var everywall:Array = [w1,w2,w3];
...
if(myHitTest(hero,everywall))
    ...
```

Comment: Didn't know you could write for (var item:DisplayObject : arr) style for loops in AS

Comment: @BarisUsakli you can. I had to fix the syntax a little bit, as it is pretty restrictive.

Comment: Oh I see your edit now, for(var obj:Object in array) is what I use, I don't think there is a for loop that uses a : in AS3, couldn't get that to compile.

Comment: @BarisUsakli I've been doing too many non-AS3 things lately, picked the wrong syntax.

Comment: I hear you I am hitting f7 to compile while working on JS code (facepalm)

Comment: I get this error as soon as i move my player and no collision works 


TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
 at flash.display::DisplayObject/flash.display:DisplayObject::_hitTest()
 at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
 at GroupGame_fla::MainTimeline/myHitTest()
 at GroupGame_fla::MainTimeline/keydown()

Comment: @LochyMacleod I added a new version. Try the new version. Sometimes the foreach style for loop doesn't work quite right.